# How can I use all the characters of a string?

Tags: ruby

I make a string and I ask the user to insert a name. I need three of the letters they wrote

```
print "what is your name: "
a = gets.chomp
```

I want to use the first three letters. In this case is for adding other characters and create a different word. How can I separate the string? Can I do the same thing with numbers, with variables that use numbers instead of characters?

Comment: hello is `a[(1..3)]` giving you data you need?

Comment: @Bohdan `a[0..2]` (and parentheses are redundant.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

`a[0..2]`

numbers that are entered manually are considered string so there should be no problem neither.

Comment: it's to create the variable, to print it you just need to do `puts a[0..2]`